# jquery inside fancybox not working

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I am facing problems with jquery within fancybox. Basically I have a form rendered through ajax and its been loaded within fancybox. But the problem is, jquery doesn't work on the form loaded by fancybox :( but it works fine when i go to the actual form page.

I found a similar problem here http://groups.google.com/group/fancybox/browse_thread/thread/fe6f9cad7b42df79 where he says to use absolute referencing... I even tried that, but no luck.

Anybody of you have faced a similar problem?

here is my jquery code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input#user_username").click(function(e){
    alert("asaadasd");
  }); // this works fine when called through the form loaded in the page, but doesn't when the form is loaded within fancybox

  $("a#login-link, a#login-link2, a#signup-link, a#signup-link2").fancybox({
    'scrolling'   : 'no',
    'titleShow'   : false
  });

});
```

any help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your form is loaded via ajax, the `click` event will not be bound to it on `document.ready` since it's not present in the document at that time. Use [`live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) instead. This binds the event to both present and future elements in the document.

```
$("input#user_username").live("click", function(e) {
    alert("asaadasd");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use .on() now (as live is deprecated)...

```
$(document).on("click", "input#user_username", function(e) {
    alert("asaadasd");
});
```